# Authlogic no credentials provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, authlogic, mongomapper

I'm using MongoMapper, Authlogic and these codes too, https://gist.github.com/444888/e8b28196c4f4452a06b89d566a6a245eae1e9d92.

I'm having trouble when I'm skipping the authentication to log the user in directly.
According to the Authlogic, I just need to input these line of codes:

```
user = User.find(1234)    
UserSession.create(user, true)
```

and it will automatically logs in the user. But I always got this output:

```
#<UserSession: no credentials provided>
```

Is there any configuration that I need to fix or change? Like in UserSession.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Authlogic v2.1.6, Rails v2.3.8**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I log people in through an API token using mongomapper/authlogic

```
@session = UserSession.new(User.find_by_single_access_token(params[:token]))
@session.save
```

This is a dupe of the answer I gave over on [authlogic UserSession.create(@user) giving unauthorized_record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180453/authlogic-usersession-createuser-giving-unauthorized-record)

In that answer, the original poster stated "persistence_token was not being set when the user object was saved!"

Comment: what happens if you "puts user.inspect" after `User.find(1234)`? My gut says it will complain that user is nil

Comment: Sorry for late response. Here is the [link](http://pastie.org/private/xkxhiq1gfnwrnd3dfmsxpa) to the output.