# #<UserSession: {:unauthorized_record=>"<protected>"}>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm trying to build a "just click on your name to login" system using auth_logic. My user model has an email and name field. To login, I simply do:

```
UserSession.create(@user, true)
```

Unfortunately that doesn't result in a session being created. Using a debugger I found this message:

```
#<UserSession: {:unauthorized_record=>"<protected>"}>
```

My user model just has one line:

```
acts_as_authentic
```

User session line has this, which I found somewhere. I'm not sure what it does and I've tried with and without:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  def to_key
     new_record? ? nil : [ self.send(self.class.primary_key) ]
  end
end
```

The database (I'm also not sure if that user_sessions table is needed):

```
create_table "sessions", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "session_id", :null => false
  t.text     "data"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "sessions", ["session_id"], :name => "index_sessions_on_session_id"
add_index "sessions", ["updated_at"], :name => "index_sessions_on_updated_at"

create_table "user_sessions", :force => true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "persistence_token"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "name"
end
```

I'm using Rails 3.0.9 and my Gemfile says (I tried both the normal and the Github authlogic gem):

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem "authlogic" #, :git => 'git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```

[Here](https://github.com/Sjors/moneRideShare/tree/c5741dac3957631a075b5cae27354f89f668e281)'s the rest of the source code.

I had this problem a few days ago on a similar project and it "just went away" at some point. I just don't remember how.

Any ideas? This is driving me nuts...

Comment: Hi Sjors, I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @dorian if you only need Twitter login, this gem makes it trivial: https://github.com/mislav/twitter-login

Comment: Having the same issue as well. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution...  it looks like there are two versions of those helper method examples floating around.  There is the [one](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) that we used:

```
@current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
```

and then there is [the newer version](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example/blob/master/app/controllers/application_controller.rb) that is in some newer tutorials and examples:

```
@current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
```

Apparently, when .user (or whatever the login field is) is called on the session object, it returns the unauthorized_record, whereas .record.user returns the appropriate data.

Comment: Thanks, I switched to using the twitter-login gem some time ago, so I can't test your solution. I'm sure it will be of help to someone though.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue recently and was confused as well. I have figured out my code's specific problem so this is another potential solution.

## tl;dr

I did not understand that `#<UserSession: {:unauthorized_record=>"<protected>"}>` is still valid user session, just an unauthed one that we created ourselves. You can confirm this by calling `user` on it and you should get whatever `User` instance you passed into `UserSession.create`.

## Cause

The real issue is two fold. The `current_user` method was built with the assumption that the current user *would not* change during the lifetime of a request *and* I was calling `current_user` before creating one one to ensure I didn't have one already. It can be simplified to the following:

```
def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)

  @current_user = some_method_that_finds_a_proper_user
end
```

The key here is that my method for finding a user can return `nil`. When it does, it will define `@current_user` as `nil` and thus that cached value will always be returned on subsequent calls.

## Solutions

Here's where it gets a bit harder as it really depends on what your code needs.

1. If you do not need the `current_user` after signing a user model in with `UserSession.create` then you don't need to do anything but wait for the render or redirect. On your next request, your `current_user` will be properly set.
2. If you do not need to check for an already logged in user, remove any calls to `current_user` before `UserSession.create` if able and your first call to `current_user` will work as expected.
3. Ensure your method chain that produces `current_user` either does not use caching, does not cache `nil`s, or change the guard for these cached values to determine if the value is truthy instead of if the instance variable is defined. The guard could be changed to:

   ```
   return @current_user if !@current_user.nil? # or @current_user.present? in Rails
   ```

   Or you can use Ruby's `||=` operator and implicit return. My simplified example above could instead be:

   ```
   def current_user
     @current_user ||= some_method_that_finds_a_proper_user
   end
   ```

   or if it's not as simple

   ```
   def current_user
     @current_user ||= begin
       some_code
       doing_many
       things_here
     end
   end
   ```
4. Or your problem could be that you're having trouble writing a test for this behavior. In that case I'd rather just put an expectation on the code like

   ```
   expect(UserSession).to receive(:create).with(user)
   ```